# Turing machine moving right

Tags: turing-machines

Let $M=\left\langle Q, \Sigma, \Gamma, \delta_M, q_0, q_{a c c}, q_{r e j}\right\rangle$ be a TM whose reading head can only move to the right. Prove that $L(M) \in R E G$. For simplicity you may assume first that for all $q \in Q$ it holds that $\delta_M(q, \sqcup) \in\left\{q_{a c c}, q_{r e j}\right\} \times \Gamma \times\{R\}$. Namely, once the machine reaches the first empty cell it immediately accepts/rejects (Though it may accepts/reject at some point before reaching that first $\sqcup)$. How can you modify your solution to the general case where we can have $\delta_M(q, \sqcup)=$ $(p, \gamma, R)$ for some $p \notin\left\{q_{a c c}, q_{r e j}\right\}$ ? (That is, without the aforementioned assumption).

**here is the original question**, I built already a DFA using the states of M(the TM), well defined the transition function, and so on, I'm trying to show that L(M) = L(DFA), and having difficulties to formalize it properly.

I'm taking a word in L(M), I know that it accepted iff the TM got to q_accept, but I think I can't conclude that if word finishes in accepting state, (which is a state that belongs to accepting state in dfa too), so the word is in L(DFA), and the opposite.

how do I prove that L(M) = L(DFA)?

**the DFA i built looks something like this:**

Next, we start with a Turing machine $M=\left(Q, \Sigma, \Gamma, \delta, q_0, q_{\text {accept }}, q_{\text {reject }}\right)$ with stay put instead of left, and show how we can construct a DFA $\left(Q^{\prime}, \Sigma^{\prime}, \delta^{\prime}, q_0^{\prime}, F\right)$ that recognizes the same language. The intuition here is that $M$ cannot move left and cannot read anything it has written on the tape as soon as it moves right, and therefore it has essentially only one-way access to its input, much like a DFA.

First, we modify $M$ as follows; note that these changes do not affect the language it recognizes.

- Add a new symbol so that $M$ never writes blanks on the tape; instead, $M$ writes the new symbol when it's going to write blanks, and we extend the transition function so that upon reading this new symbol, it behaves as though it read a blank.
- When $M$ transitions into $q_{\text {reject }}$ or $q_{\text {accept }}$, the reading head moves right (and never stays put).
  Set $Q^{\prime}=Q, \Sigma^{\prime}=\Sigma, q_0^{\prime}=q_0$, and consider the transition function:
  $$
  \delta^{\prime}(q, \sigma)= \begin{cases}q, & \text { if } q \in\left\{q_{\text {accept }}, q_{\text {re ject }}\right\} \\ q_{\text {reject }}, & \text { if } M \text { starting at state } q \text { and reading } \sigma \text { keeps staying put. } \\ q^{\prime}, & \text { where } q^{\prime} \text { is the state the } M \text { enters when it first moves right } \\ \text { upon starting at state } q \text { and reading } \sigma .\end{cases}
  $$
  (for $q \in Q$ and $\sigma \in \Sigma$ ). Observe that there are finitely many state-alphabet pairs, $M$ either ends up either staying put and looping, or eventually moves right, and thus $\delta^{\prime}$ is well-defined. Finally, we define $F$ to be the set containing $q_{\text {accept }}$ and all states $q \in Q, q \neq q_{\text {accept }}, q_{\text {reject }}$ such that $M$ starting at $q$ and reading blanks, eventually enters $q_{\text {accept }}$.

thank you :)

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics.  You can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).  Don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Comment: Please credit the  source of all copied material / material written by others.

Comment: I translated this to latex, would love for some help, credit for HUJI for the questions and so on

Comment: Please [edit] the question to credit the source in the question.  Our referencing guidelines are here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing.  I don't know what "HUJI" refers to.